# Regular Expression C# - Match 4 or 5 digits preceded by inconsistently formatted string

Tags: regex

I am looking for some help matching a 4 or 5 digit string from within another string.

The digits are preceded by "JC" but it is inconsistently formatted.

Examples:

```
JC1234
JC 1234
J.C1234
J.C 1234
J/C1234
J/C 1234
J C1234
J C 1234
```

The character between J and C can be anything, or whitespace.

I would appreciate some help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this regex : `/J\W?C\s?(\d{4,5})/` :

```
/
  J\W?C      # J + single non-word character (optional) + C
  \s?        # optional single space
  (\d{4,5})  # 4 or 5 digits
/x
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/tI4kW0/1)

Comment: @Trevor note that it won't work if there's any word character present in-between `J` and `C`.

Comment: Avinash, that is actually want I want, but thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
J[./ ]?C ?\d+
```

See [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/28).

**Explanation**

- `J` matches a literal char
- `[./ ]?` optionally matches a period, slash or space
- `C` matches a C
- `?` matches an optional space
- `\d+` matches digits

**To use it in C#, you could iterate like this (or use `Matches`)**

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"J[./ ]?C ?\d+");
Match matchResult = myRegex.Match(yourString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    // do something with matchResult.Value
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex to capture only the digits which are preceded by JC.

```
J.?C.?(\d{4,5})
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/29)

**Explanation:**

- `J` Matches a literal J.
- `.` Matches any character except a newline character.`?` after the dot character makes it as an optional one.
- `C.?` Matches `C` and the following  optional character.
- `(\d{4,5})` Capture the digits which ranges from 4 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in the number extraction from these strings, then you can use just \d+:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
```

Comment: I need to only match if preceeded by the string